# Passing array to a function (C/CPP)

Tags: c, pointers

I came to know about two method of passing 1 D array to a function.

```
void bubbleSort(int *arr, int len);  //Here I am passing arr as a pointer to the array.


void bubbleSort(int arr[], int len);  //Here I am not sure..  but arr is a const pointer.
```

calling of both the function are same, then what is the difference and what is the benefit for the two function definition?

Answer (score 2):

The actual value passed is the same. In the latter case, you cannot change the value of `arr` inside the function `bubbleSort`, since the type of `arr` is "array" and array names are a bit like constant pointers.